# MVC4 DTO's and Many to Many Relationships with extension methods for WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, code-first

I need some assistance in learning how DTO's and Extension methods work with Many to Many relationships in EF5 Code First MVC4.

I have the following DTO's

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Mirtol.Web.Models
{

public class TaskDetail
{
    public DateTime DueDate {get;set;}
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Phase { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string overdue { get; set; }

    public List<GroupDetail> Groups { get; set; }

}
}

using System;
namespace Mirtol.Web.Models
{

public class GroupDetail
{

    public string GroupName {get;set;}
    public string GroupDescription { get; set; }

}
}
```

On top of these I have The following extensions;

```
using Mirtol.Web.Models;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Mirtol.Web.Extensions
{
public static class TaskDetailExtensions
{
    public static TaskDetail ToTaskDetail(this Task task)
    {
        var success = "success";
        var warning = "warning";
        var error = "error";


 return new TaskDetail
                {
                    Id = task.Id,
                    Name = task.Name,
                    Description = task.Description,
                    Status = task.Status,
                    Phase = task.Phase != null ? task.Phase.Name : string.Empty,
                    Project = task.Project != null ? task.Project.ShortName : string.Empty,
                    StartDate = task.StartDateTime,
                    DueDate = task.DueDate,
                    overdue = task.DueDate > System.DateTime.Now ? success : task.DueDate < System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) ? error : warning,


                };
        }
    }
}


using Mirtol.Entities.Mir;
using Mirtol.Web.Models;

namespace Mirtol.Web.Extensions
{
public static class GroupDetailExtensions
{
    public static GroupDetail ToGroupDetail(this Group group)
    {

        return new GroupDetail
            {
                GroupName = group.Name != null ? group.Name: string.Empty,
                GroupDescription = group.Description !=null ? group.Description: string.Empty,

         };
    }
}
}
```

So my tasks controller has an action;

```
    public IEnumerable<TaskDetail> GetUserProjectTasks(int id, string ustr, int uid)
    {
        var projectUTasks = taskRepository.GetUserProjectTasks(id, ustr, mirtolSecurity.CurrentUserId).Distinct();

        return projectUTasks.OrderByDescending(x => x.DueDate).Select(x => x.ToTaskDetail());
    }
```

which returns toTaskDetail. and includes "Groups"

What I am struggling with is in TaskDetailExtension and TaskDetaail, how do I reflect the fact that a task can belong to many groups and groups can have many tasks? CF takes care of this on my entity classes and the relationships seem to be set up fine there.

My thought was something like 
    Groups = task.Groups(x => x.Groups.ToGroupDetail()),

in the TaskDetailExtension ?

Any help appreciated.

John

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your Task has a IEnumerable called Groups.
You need two extension methods in these kind of situations. One that will convert your child model and another that will convert the list of your child models.

```
public static GroupDetail ToGroupDetail(this Group group)
{
    return new GroupDetail { .. your mappings };
}

public static IEnumerable<GroupDetail> ToGroupDetailList(this IEnumerable<Group> groups)
{
    return groups.Select(g => g.ToGroupDetail());
}
```

Then include following line in your ToTaskDetail after other properties.

```
Groups = task.Groups.ToGroupDetailList()
```

If the task.Groups is a IQueriable you need to change the ToGroupDetailList extension method to take a IQueriable instead of IEnumerable. Hope this helps